# Boundschecker does not terminate execution

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, devpartner

I'm trying to generate a memory leak report using BoundsChecker 9.0.931.1 (BC.exe) through command line. The command I use is:

**BC.exe /B sessionlog.dbpcl /XD xmlout.xml /OUT errorfile.txt /S /NOLOGO /W D:\Test\debug__bin D:\Test\debug\bin\Application.exe "input.txt"**

I have instrumented the DLLs used by my application and the report can be generated using the GUI application of BoundsChecker. But, when I try to run the same through command line, after my application has done processing and is terminated, the BoundsChecker process BC.exe keeps running forever and does not generate any report.

Does anybody have an idea whats going wrong?

Comment: Did you tried to contact the support team DevPartner?

Answer (score 0):

Team DevPartner calling.

BC should terminate, of course.

Two questions: 
(1) Can you try this with BoundsChecker 10.0? 
(2) Would you mind sending me the test case so I can see if I can replicate the problem?